# Can I limit jQuery UI datepicker to select only Wednesdays and Thursdays of the 2nd and 3rd week of each month?

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>

<body>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="" value="" id=""  class="datepicker" />


<script>
$(function() {
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        showMonthAfterYear: true,
        beforeShowDay: disableSomeDay
    });

    // A function to run before showing the date (beforeShowDay)
    function disableSomeDay(date) {
        var month = date.getMonth();
        var dates = date.getDate();
        var year = date.getFullYear();

        //The date corresponding to the array is returned with false at the 0th index.
        for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
            if($.inArray(year + '-' +(month+1) + '-' + dates,disabledDays) != -1) {
                return [false];
            }
        }

        //Wed and neck only
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day != 0 && day != 1 && day != 2 && day != 5 && day != 6 && day != 7)];

    }

    $(function() {
        $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });

});  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

in jquery ui datepicker

Can I only select Wednesday and Thursday of the 2nd and 3rd week of each month? The option does not have a description of the active week.
Is there any way to make active week in jquery UI datepicker?